# Pixel misalignment issue

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, export

I am trying to export a raster from "ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY" from GEE while maintaining the preciseness of pixel location.

But it turns out that the nominal scale returned is actually incorrect.It returns a result of 111319.49079327357, when really the value should be 11131.949079327357.

Therefore, when I try to use the crsTransform function in the export to maintain pixel location accuracy, the pixels are the incorrect size, and my manual scale call is ignored.

Looking for solutions for this!

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6f8e73a166cf4495456700fc955bbc40?hl=it

```
var test = mean.projection().getInfo().transform;
print(test)

var myScale = mean.projection().nominalScale();
print(myScale);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: mean,
  description: 'ERA_test_0518',
  crs:'EPSG:4326',
  scale: 11131.949079327357,
  region: southeast_boundaries,
  crsTransform: test,
    
});
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of the numbers you gave, `111319.49079327357` and `11131.949079327357`. Not only is one 10 times as big as the other, the only other difference is the first two digits after the decimal are transposed. I think you may have mis-transcribed.

Comment: Yes! The value returned by the code var myScale = mean.projection().nominalScale() is, in fact, 10 times higher than the value actually should be. I am not sure if this is a bug, or why this is happening, but that is the problem!